# Mysql optimized query and index for exclusion

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, mariadb

Mysql optimized query and index with exclusion

In the case of a select on a high volume table with a select criteria excluding results, what are the possible alternatives?

for example with the following table:

```
+----+---+---+----+----+
| id | A | B | C  | D  |
+----+---+---+----+----+
| 1  | a | b | c  | d  |
| 2  | a | b | c  | d  |
| 3  | a | b | c1 | d1 |
| 4  | a | b | c2 | d  |
| 5  | a | b | c  | d2 |
| 6  | a | b | c  | d2 |
+----+---+---+----+----+
```

I would like to select all the tuples (C,D) where A=a and B=b and (C!=c or D!=d)

```
SELECT C,D FROM my_table WHERE A=a AND B=b AND (C!=c OR D!=d) GROUP BY C,D;
```

expected result:

```
(c1,d1)
(c2,d)
(c,d2)
```

I tried to add an index like that: `CREATE INDEX idx_my_index ON my_table(A, B, C, D);` but response times are still very long

NB: I'm using MariadDB 10.3

The explain:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+----------------+---------------+---------+-------------+-----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys  | key           | key_len | ref         | rows      | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+----------------+---------------+---------+-------------+-----------+--------------------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | my_table  | ref   | idx_my_index   | idx_my_index  | 6       | const,const | 12055772  | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+----------------+---------------+---------+-------------+-----------+--------------------------+
```

Is there some improvement to add on my index, on mariadb config or another select to do that?

Specific solution: If we use this query as a subquery we can use the FirstMatch strategy to avoid the full scan of the table. this is described into https://mariadb.com/kb/en/firstmatch-strategy/

```
SELECT * FROM my__second_table tbis
WHERE (tbis.C, tbis.D) 
IN (SELECT C,D FROM my_table WHERE A=a AND B=b AND (C!=c OR D!=d));
```

Comment: So, mariadb is using your index. Judging from the index length, it probably uses the index just for A=a AND B=b conditions. You may want try to create two indexes: a  - b - c and a - b - d and use a union of two queries instead of the `or` condition.

Comment: @Shadow - I predict that will be slower -- Two 12M-row index scans plus a costly `UNION DISTINCT`.  Only if `(A,B,C)` generates very few rows will it be efficient -- but `(A,B,C,D)` may do that anyway.

Comment: @Shadow , I confirm this proposal is slower than the original.

Answer (score 0):

Your index is optimal.  Discussion:

```
INDEX(A, B,   -- see Note 1
      C, D)   -- see note 2
```

Note 1:  A,B can be in either order.  These will be used for filtering on `=` to find possible rows.  Confirmed by "const,const".

Note 2:  C,D can be in either order.  `!=` does not work well for filtering, hence these come after A and B.  They are included here to make the index "covering".  Confirmed by "Using index".

"response times are still very long" -- 12M rows in the table?  How many rows before the `GROUP BY`?  How many rows in the result?  (These *might* give us clues into where to go next.)

"Alternative".  Probably `SELECT DISTINCT ...` instead of `SELECT ... GROUP BY ...` would run at the same speed.  (But you could try it.  Also, the `EXPLAIN` might be the same`; the result should be the same.)

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it might give some more clues, such as `NULL`/`NOT NULL` and Engine type.  (I don't hold out much hope here.)

Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECGT ...` -- This *might* give some more insight.  Also:  Turn on the Optimizer Trace.

Comment: The `SELECT DISTINCT` doesn't improve the response time, but since I'm requesting another table using the tuples I found with my original request then I found a solution to avoid 'covering' the full SCAN of the table. This is described into https://mariadb.com/kb/en/firstmatch-strategy/ , and it solved my problem but I'm not sure this is the best answer here.

Comment: @karement - I don't think FirstMatch is relevant.  With it, the resultset would exclude `(c2,d)`.